# RestController Mono<T> return type vs RequestEntity<T>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-restcontroller

I am new to Spring WebFlux, and had some questions regarding its use with RestController.

```
@RestController
public class SomeRestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/get-mono")
    public Mono<SomeType> getSomeType() {
      return Mono.just(new SomeType());
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/get-request-entity")
    public RequestEntity<SomeType> getSomeType() {
      SomeType someType = Mono.just(new SomeType()).block();
  
      return ResponseEntity
              .ok()
              .header(HttpHeaders.VARY, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE)
              .body(someType)
    }
```

Are there any differences between the two approaches? Would one perform better than the other? Can these two types of request methods be specified in the same RestController? I know blocking is generally not recommended for reactive streams. Is it generally acceptable to have a mix of reactive and non-reactive data sources? Any sources or reading material would be greatly appreciated

Comment: As you said, if you're going reactive, you should generally go entirely reactive. _Why_ do you want to return a blocking `ResponseEntity` instead of `Mono<ResponseEntity<T>>`?

Comment: yes the first will perform better because you are blocking in a non-blocking framework. You are saying that blocking is "generally not recommended" which is faulty. In a fully reactive application, blocking should never be done. And the reading material you are looking for is the official reactor documentation.